# Rails existing app adding user sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an existing rails app with Mongo DB.Currently the app can be accessed by anyone that is every method in Portfolio controller and customer controller. Now I want that Portfolio controller should only be accessed by sign in user. How can I do that. I tried using active_admin but was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for **User Authentication**. Try any authentication plugin like Devise or Clearance to sign in and distinguish individual users (more options [here](http://www.plugingeek.com/categories/user-authentication-ruby)) or, even better at first, try building your own authentication solution alongside some of these excellent [RailsCasts on User authentication](http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=authentication) (the paid episodes are totally worth it!). You'll learn how the different moving parts fit together real quick.

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to consider using the Sorcery (https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery) gem as another option. It has links to the railscasts on the github repo there which helped a lot, and myself as a beginner found the wiki to be incredibly in-depth.  Super easy to use.